# It is possible to predefine ajax arguments without ajaxSetup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to change some of ajax arguments between calls without duplicate all ajax logic for example:

```
var options = {}
if(condition) {
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data
   }
} else {
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
   }
}

$.ajax({url, options})...rest of code
```

But by this way it doesn't work properly (ajax call is done but without data inside). There is some method to that without using ajaxSetup() which is not recommended??

Comment: You seem to be looking for `{url, ...options}`, or `$.ajax(url, options)`, or define the `url` as part of the options object and call `$.ajax(options)`

Comment: Thanks a lot ```ajax({url, ...options})``` works. I tried use spread operator before and It didn't work but maybe It fails in other place before.